# What exactly does the 'Page Consumptions' Facebook metric mean?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Page Consumptions - The number of times people clicked on any of your content without generating a story (total count). Daily, weekly, monthly, by consumption type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is referring to the number of times that people have clicked on content posted on your page without generating a post in their own feed.

For example, I might click on a link on your page without sharing the link in my own feed (such that nothing related to your content appears in my feed). This counts as a consumption not generating a story.